# Matrix Linear Transformations in R3

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

I find this to be a very interesting problem. I extracted the vectors into a[1 5 -3] and b[2 -1 4]. For part (a), I know that the subspace is simply a space within the space R3. How would one go about proving this?

In part (b), I thought it might be useful to implement Gram-Schmidt and let [1 5 -3] = x1 and let x2 = [2 -1 4], and then let v2 = x2 -(x2*v2)/(v1*v1) * vector v1. Then the basis will consist of x1 and v2.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The set of $(1,5, -3)$ and $(2, -1, 4)$ is a basis. For the first part, use the theorem "a span of vectors is a subspace".

Answer (score 1):

To prove (a) you have to verify:

(1) $0\in V$, which is obvious,

(2) $\forall x, y \in V$ and $\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}\ \ \ ax+by\in V$.

$x=\begin{bmatrix} a+2b \\ 5a-b \\ -3a+4b \end{bmatrix}\ \ $ and $ \ \ 
y=\begin{bmatrix} c+2d \\ 5c-d \\ -3c+4d \end{bmatrix}\ \  $ so:

$ (\alpha x+\beta y)=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha(a+2b) +\beta(c+2d) \\ \alpha(5a-b)+\beta(5c-d) \\ \alpha (-3a+4b) +\beta(-3c+4d) \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha(a+c)+2\beta(b+d)\\ \alpha5(a+c)-\beta (b+d)\\-3\alpha(a+c)+4\beta(b+d)\end{bmatrix}\ \ $ which is still a vector of V.

Then V is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$\ $

To solve (b) you have to find a set of linearly independent vectors such as they generate V.

$\{(1, 5, -3), (2, -1, 4)\}$ satisfies both the properties.